# Only run setUp when a specific test requires it

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

How would I limit running a setUp method to only run when a specific test is run, e.g.

```
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    
    setUpClass(cls):
        #requirements for all tests

    def test1(self):
        #something

    def test2(self):
        #something else

    def setUp(self):
        #requirements for test 3

    def test3(self):
        #something requiring setup
```

In this case, I only want to run setUp when test3 is called

Comment: call setUp inside test3?

Comment: Yep that's done it, wasn't sure you could call setUp inside the test using it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a test-specific setup method inside test method, e.g.:

```
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    
    setUpClass(cls):
        #requirements for all tests

    def test1(self):
        #something

    def test2(self):
        #something else

    def setUp(self):
        #requirements for test 3

    def test3(self):
        self.prepareForTest3();
        #execute test case

    def prepareForTest3(self):
        #do preparations here
```